# Join 2 SELECT statements with same condition

Tags: mysql

I have 2 SELECT statements:

```
set @student_id = (select ID from student where student.name='A');

SELECT course_id, title, credits
FROM course
WHERE course_id IN (SELECT course_id FROM takes 
WHERE takes.ID = @student_id AND grade != 'F');

SELECT course_id, grade
FROM takes
WHERE course_id IN (SELECT course_id FROM takes 
WHERE takes.ID = @student_id AND grade != 'F');
```

Since the results has course_id as the common column, I tried to join them as below but got wrong results.

````
SELECT DISTINCT course.course_id, course.title, course.credits, takes.grade
FROM course INNER JOIN takes on course.course_id = takes.course_id
WHERE course.course_id IN (SELECT course_id FROM takes 
WHERE takes.ID = @student_id AND grade != 'F');```

Any help?
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT course.course_id, course.title, course.credits, takes.grade
FROM course JOIN takes on course.course_id = takes.course_id
WHERE  takes.ID = @student_id AND takes.grade != 'F'
```